# 404 with active URL rewriting

Tags: url, seo

I am trying to accomplish clean URLs.

I have turned on URL Rewriting in the Global Configuration.

I have renamed htaccess.txt to .htaccess and left it as it is, except for RewriteBase which I changed to `RewriteBase /srv/http/joomla` as that is where my Joomla installation resides.

mod_rewrite is enabled in Apache.

There are no .htaccess files above the Joomla installation in the file hierarchy.

When I use a category list and follow its link that URL is nice and clean, but results in a 404 error. The old URLs that **include** .../**index.php**/article-name still work.
What's wrong?

Full .htaccess:

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

 RewriteBase /srv/http/joomla

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical    folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: Are you enabling also "Search Engine Friendly URLs" in global configuration?

Comment: Are you running on Apache?, if you are running on Nginx or IIS .htaccess won´t work

Comment: Have you tried just commenting RewriteBase , normally it is not necesary to change it

Comment: Oh wow, commenting it out actually solved the problem. I feel a little dumb right now. Thanks, man!

Comment: glad you solve it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Trivially all I had to change was comment out `RewriteBase ...`.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteBase must be with slash at end, something like this:
RewriteBase /srv/http/joomla/

To use seo urls in Joomla both settings "Search Engine Friendly URLs" and "Use URL Rewriting" must be activated, see screen.

[image: joomla seo urls settings]